# javaCC parser generator can't handle EOF

Tags: java, io, javacc

This is the code I've been using which I copied from [here](http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-Tutorial/javacc-tutorial.pdf) (from page 13 on; I could succesfully execute and parse an addition example from an input.txt file which contained numbers and + signs sintactically correct i.e.  `4 +   2 returns six`, but  `4 ++ 2 gives an error`)

```
options {
    STATIC = false ;
}

PARSER_BEGIN ( Calculator )
    import java.io.PrintStream ;

class Calculator
{
    public static void main ( String [] args)
    throws ParseException, TokenMgrError, NumberFormatException
    {
        Calculator parser = new Calculator( System.in ) ;
        parser.Start(System.out) ;
    }
    double previousValue = 0.0 ;
}
PARSER_END ( Calculator )

SKIP : { " " }
TOKEN : { < EOL : "\n" | "\r" | "\r\n" > }
TOKEN : { < PLUS : "+" > }
TOKEN : { < NUMBER : <DIGITS> | <DIGITS> "." <DIGITS> | <DIGITS> "." | "." <DIGITS> > }
TOKEN : { <#DIGITS : (["0"-"9"])+ > }

void Start(PrintStream printStream) throws NumberFormatException :
{}
{
    (
        previousValue = Expression()
        <EOL>
        {printStream.println(previousValue) ; }
    )*
    <EOF>
}

double Expression () throws NumberFormatException :
{
    double i ;
    double value ;  
}
{
    value = Primary ()
    (
        <PLUS>
        i = Primary()
        { value += i ; }
    )*
    { return value ; }
}

double Primary () throws NumberFormatException :
{
    Token t ;
}
{
    t = <NUMBER>
    { return Double.parseDouble( t.image ) ; }
}
```

´

```
C:\Users\Jay\workspace\javaCC>javacc calculator0.jj
```

Generates all the required java files correctly, all those I compile with no errors nor warnings with

```
javac *.java
```

But then, When I try to run

```
java Calculator < input.txt
```

where input.txt contains

> 4   + 2 + 2

for some reason in this new version I get

```
Exception in thread "main" ParseException: Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 11.
Was expecting one of:
    <EOL> ...
    "+" ...

        at Calculator.generateParseException(Calculator.java:218)
        at Calculator.jj_consume_token(Calculator.java:156)
        at Calculator.Start(Calculator.java:27)
        at Calculator.main(Calculator.java:10)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The grammar requires one expression per line. That was a deliberate design decision. Perhaps the tutorial could have explained that decision better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. It was a little bug on that PDF and I was able to solve it. Only three characters needed to be added to fix that bug.

The answer is to change:

```
void Start(PrintStream printStream) throws NumberFormatException :
{}
{
    (
        previousValue = Expression()
        <EOL>
        {printStream.println(previousValue) ; }
    )*
    <EOF>
}
```

for

```
void Start(PrintStream printStream) throws NumberFormatException :
{}
{
    (
        previousValue = Expression()
        (<EOL>)*
        {printStream.println(previousValue) ; }
    )*
    <EOF>
}
```

And it works like a charm.

Comment: The word "bug" seems a little harsh. :-)

Comment: Yes. The only issue with that is that `Expression`s are can follow each other without any `<EOL>` between them; that wasn't allowed in the original version.